# 2 miners on private network slow sync

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain

I am running 2 miners and 1 non-mining node using docker. Just can't see the 2 miners work in tandem. Each can assemble its DAG. Only seems to work with a single miner.
I am using `Geth/peer1/v1.8.16-stable-477eb093/linux-amd64/go1.9.4` from ethereum/go-client:alpine.

Nodes are configured through static-nodes.json and I can reach each node on port 30303 (tested with nc -zv)

```
[                                                                                                                                                               
"enode://b27ff3191f16c7de4c9037eaf419e8d3f25c847b551dd15100c5a375f02032ca5275af29cb29c64258e99c450e0d8825010a13d18c0d404b4c95fb8a1ee9e699@172.17.0.3:30303",    
"enode://29bd9b51c2b7f031bf5be15d4cb6028300d4d254ace507bfb5ce283121566f3cd3d96ba303c3ce5c857a7daa29522999cbe545ea64f66c639f4ec526ae3f7cb8@172.17.0.4:30303",    
"enode://dc014606c0ee47f9ce917c9497b1a1b2819dfdc4f2d574965b6aa38f447b3c5721f6a63e8942f97cef41f656cce2429a698a0690f48d2faa0019a0026c4cbca2@172.17.0.5:30303"     
]
```

Genesis has low difficulty

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId"        : 11,
    "homesteadBlock" : 0,
    "eip150Block"    : 0,
    "eip150Hash"     : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip155Block"    : 0,
    "eip158Block"    : 0,
    "byzantiumBlock" : 0,
    "ethash"         : {}
  },
  "coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty" : "0x100",
  "extraData"  : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit"   : "0xffffffff",
  "nonce"      : "0x0000000000000042",
  "mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp"  : "0x00",
  "alloc"      : {}
}
```

When I start 2 miners, both mining nodes seem to hang after DAG is built. NOTE: see edits below.
I can trigger block creation if I stop one miner.
Below is peer1 's output (after a restart and killing peer2 to get some 11 blocks created)
It just hangs there and nothing happens.

```
WARN [09-29|16:21:19.909] Sanitizing cache to Go's GC limits       provided=1024 updated=660
INFO [09-29|16:21:19.922] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [09-29|16:21:19.948] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/peer1/v1.8.16-stable-477eb093/linux-amd64/go1.9.4
INFO [09-29|16:21:19.949] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/root/.ethereum/geth/chaindata cache=495 handles=1024
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.485] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 11 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 0 EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: 0 Constantinople: <nil> Engine: ethash}"
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.485] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/root/.ethereum/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.486] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/root/.ethash               count=2
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.486] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=11
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.497] Loaded most recent local header          number=11 hash=f506b2…e1a16f td=1444928 age=1h6m40s
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.498] Loaded most recent local full block      number=11 hash=f506b2…e1a16f td=1444928 age=1h6m40s
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.498] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=11 hash=f506b2…e1a16f td=1444928 age=1h6m40s
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.501] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.513] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.513] Starting P2P networking
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.517] Stats daemon started
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.517] RLPx listener up                         self="enode://b27ff3191f16c7de4c9037eaf419e8d3f25c847b551dd15100c5a375f02032ca5275af29cb29c64258e99c450e0d8825010a13d18c0d404b4c95fb8a1ee9e699@[::]:30303?discport=0"
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.530] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/var/run/geth.ipc
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.530] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1000000000
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.531] Updated mining threads                   threads=1
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.531] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1000000000
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.531] Etherbase automatically configured       address=0xFDb60C5297aE226dd8B8813cd94995813eEaDd22
INFO [09-29|16:21:20.531] Commit new mining work                   number=12 sealhash=aeaead…9c6d63 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=176.2µs
```

Below are the commands I use from a batch file (including the netstats container)
Each container has its separate folder mapped into its container.

```
docker run -d --rm -v /c/Users/P33/playground/p2p/shared/peer1:/root --name peer1 --link netstats ethereum/client-go:alpine --nodiscover --networkid 11 --mine --minerthreads 1 --ipcpath /var/run/geth.ipc --identity peer1 --syncmode "full" --ethstats "peer1:password@ws://netstats:3000"
docker run -d --rm -v /c/Users/P33/playground/p2p/shared/peer2:/root --name peer2 --link netstats ethereum/client-go:alpine --nodiscover --networkid 11 --mine --minerthreads 1 --ipcpath /var/run/geth.ipc --identity peer2 --syncmode "full" --ethstats "peer2:password@ws://netstats:3000"
docker run -d --rm -v /c/Users/P33/playground/p2p/shared/peer3:/root --name peer3 --link netstats -p 8545:8545 ethereum/client-go:alpine --nodiscover --networkid 11 --rpc --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*" --ipcpath /var/run/geth.ipc --identity peer3 --syncmode "full" --ethstats "peer3:password@ws://netstats:3000"
```

Any thoughts? TIA!

### EDIT 1

When adding a 60s delay between the launch of miner1 and miner2, I observe the DAG process completes with miner1 in the lead; start of mining; then both hang.
I then stop and re-launch with the same 60s delay. First miner stays in the lead then reaches a "Mining too far in the future" (at about 80 blocks) and again both miners hang there.

I was hoping to see both miners compete and randomly "win" the next block as they are sharing identical resources on the same laptop...

### EDIT 2

I managed to get this small network of 2 miners and one peer going a little longer by doing the following:

- start first miner and pause for 60s
- edit static-nodes.json on first miner to point to other miner and peer
- second miner only points to peer and leaves first miner alone
- peer points to both miners

I had previously each member pointing to the other two (NOK).
Having miner 2 point to miner 1 (even after delay) would eventually halt the block generation after 20-30 blocks on this laptop.

With this setup I can reach 190+ blocks... still not sure why...

vmodule=fetcher=6,downloader=6 logs below

miner 1

```
DEBUG[10-05|08:00:20.959] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|08:00:40.959] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|08:01:00.960] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|08:01:20.962] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|08:01:40.963] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|08:02:00.964] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|08:02:20.965] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|08:02:40.965] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|08:03:00.966] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|08:03:20.966] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
```

miner 2

```
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:36.651] Queued propagated block                  peer=36d0dbecc9bbf66d number=192 hash=4fda3f…90ff75 queued=1
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:36.651] Importing propagated block               peer=36d0dbecc9bbf66d number=192 hash=4fda3f…90ff75
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:36.758] Queued propagated block                  peer=36d0dbecc9bbf66d number=193 hash=3c3c32…c9e9b3 queued=1
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:36.758] Importing propagated block               peer=36d0dbecc9bbf66d number=193 hash=3c3c32…c9e9b3
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:44.029] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|07:57:04.029] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|07:57:24.030] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|07:57:44.030] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|07:58:04.030] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[10-05|07:58:24.031] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
```

peer 3 (not mining)

```
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:33.362] Inserted new block                       number=189 hash=b0209e…4edc82 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 elapsed=140.556ms
INFO [10-05|07:56:33.363] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=143.084ms mgasps=0.000 number=189 hash=b0209e…4edc82 cache=27.26kB
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:33.371] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:35.048] Inserted new block                       number=190 hash=aecf0c…285ae1 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 elapsed=54.696ms
INFO [10-05|07:56:35.048] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=54.858ms  mgasps=0.000 number=190 hash=aecf0c…285ae1 cache=27.26kB
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:35.048] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:36.434] Inserted new block                       number=191 hash=f33bf0…b82196 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 elapsed=54.571ms
INFO [10-05|07:56:36.434] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=68.644ms  mgasps=0.000 number=191 hash=f33bf0…b82196 cache=27.26kB
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:36.435] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:36.703] Inserted new block                       number=192 hash=4fda3f…90ff75 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 elapsed=12.576ms
INFO [10-05|07:56:36.703] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=12.688ms  mgasps=0.000 number=192 hash=4fda3f…90ff75 cache=27.26kB
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:36.703] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:36.802] Inserted new block                       number=193 hash=3c3c32…c9e9b3 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 elapsed=15.051ms
INFO [10-05|07:56:36.802] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1  txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=16.326ms  mgasps=0.000 number=193 hash=3c3c32…c9e9b3 cache=27.26kB
DEBUG[10-05|07:56:36.802] Reinjecting stale transactions           count=0
```

### EDIT 3

I tried different topologies, reducing the connections between peers.
Even with { Miner 1 -> Miner 2 -> Peer 3 }, the setup hangs after a while (with delay after starting first miner) or immediately. Not sure at this point where else to look...

### EDIT 4

So what I can observe is that miner 1 starts mining blocks as it gets a headstart. Miner 2 starts syncing. Once the situation occurs of "mining too far in the future" both hang at message "wait 2s" - as when I start immediately both miners without delay. I have limited each miner to 1 thread.
When I stop miner 2 while it's generating blocks, miner 2 picks up. But when miner 2 is stopped, the first does not pick up again....

### EDIT 5

I changed the title from stalling to slow sync...
I left the 3 nodes running and one of the miners produced a new block after about 30 minutes. In the screen capture below, 2 miners are at the bottom and a non-mining node at the top. Each miner points to the regular peer. I am on SSD 2ith 16GB RAM - each container gets 2GB and I set the Geth cache to 512KB.

[image: two miners]

Comment: tried with --verbosity 5 and noticed some odd stuff with "connected to self" - I am using the same static-nodes.json for all nodes, so perhaps I have to tailor it for each...

Comment: no luck - even when excluding self from static-nodes.json, the two miners seem to hang

Comment: Do you have a log when miners 'hang'?

Comment: Just plugged the output of docker logs -f peer1 into a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jdevoo/c767f62bb6a7a357bfc0708979d586a0) - note this is with --nat "none" and verbosity 9 and the bottom two chunks keep repeating

Comment: The netstats connection appears to fail, but I nothing related to mining failing. It seems to connect correctly to the other peer.

Comment: it's so weird... something to do with docker for windows perhaps? The netstats complains about bad block because it hangs on block 0... driving me nuts... If I kill a peer, the other picks up and starts mining

Comment: just tried unlocking accounts on each miner but no luck with that either...

Comment: just tried a different topology: where peer3 (non-mining) is linked with each miner but miners not with each other - didn't help either

Comment: To discard thing any unrelated issue I'd launch the two miners but without mining and see if they connect between them (ie I'd disable ethstats until everything is working just to avoid clutering the logs). If that is ok then start mining with the first miner until it has produced several blocks then start the second miner. It may be that miners are mining but they do not create blocks because the difficulty is too high.

Comment: I noticed using --verbosity 1 and --vmodule makes it easy to focus on specific aspects

Answer (score 2):

Bumping the default docker 2GB per container to 3GB solved my problem. I now have a fast 3-peer 2-miner private network.